# bash copyright changes to question mark

Tags: bash, shell

My Bash script runs a query placing the returned data into a file:

```
  result=$($ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus -s $DB_USER/$DB_PASS@$ORACLE_SID <<END>>$RETURN_FILE
  set linesize 32767 pagesize 0 feedback off verify off heading off echo off;
  $QUERY
  exit;
END
)
```

The output in the file has copyright, register and hyphens all changed to **?**

I have viewed this multiple ways, so it is not the editor, it is the file itself.

How can I correct this?

I have checked locale and from other posts I think it is correct:

```
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TIME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_COLLATE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="en_US.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=
```

My version info is:

```
LSB_VERSION=base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server release 6.8 (Santiago)
```

BTW-this was originally a ColdFusion process running the same query against the same DB and the output file showed everything correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out export NLS_LANG=AMERICAN_AMERICA.AL32UTF8 was the answer (Oracle issue not Linux).